# FetchRequests from three entities with to-many relations, Core Data

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, nsfetchrequest

this website has been an extremely helpful resource for me during the last weeks, since I just started coding in XCode. Now I came across a Core Data problem that I'd know how to solve in a common database, but not in Core Data and I'd be glad if someone could point me to the solution. I'd be fine with some keywords to do further research on, so here's the issue:

Let's take a recipe example, linking ingredients to recipes: say you have an entity of ingredients, each of which can occur in several recipes, and you have an entity of recipes, each of which has a name and contains several ingredients. What's the best Data model for this?

What I did was to introduce a third table which links the recipe names to the ingredients, so it just consists of two relations (both to-many) pointing at the ingredient entity and at the recipe entity. But how can I fetch the ingredients for a given recipe now?

Probably I need to use a Fetch Request, but I need to make two steps in fetching - basically saying "fetch all instances of ingredient entities that are related to the objects in the translation-entity which are related to my current recipe"... any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

To model this in Core Data, you can take either of two approaches:

1. Use a pair of to-many relationships, one in each direction. If the `Recipe` entity has a to-many `ingredients` relation, the inverse of that would be the `Ingredient` entity's to-many `recipes` relation.
2. Use an intermediate entity like `RecipeIngredient`, as you seem to have done. Both `Recipe` and `Ingredient` can have a to-many relationship to `RecipeIngredient`, but the inverse of each of those can be to-one.

Whichever approach you use, you still only need a single fetch request. Say you want to get the ingredients for the recipe named "Brownies". You'd create a fetch request for the entity `Recipe` and use a predicate that selects `name like "Brownies"`. That'll give you the set of recipes that match the request. You can then access the ingredients for any of those recipes using the relations -- that is, you don't need another fetch request for ingredients. Say you took the second approach and `Recipe` has a to-many relation to `RecipeIngredients` called `ingredientList`, and `RecipeIngredient` has a to-one relationship that is `ingredient`:

```
Recipe *recipe = [recipes anyObject];
NSSet *ingredientList = recipe.ingredientList;
for (RecipeIngredient *item in ingredientList) {
    Ingredient *ingredient = item.ingredient;
    //...do something with the ingredient...
}
```

If you instead used the first approach, you could access the set of ingredients a little more directly:

```
Recipe *recipe = [recipes anyObject];
NSSet *ingredients = recipe.ingredients;
for (Ingredient *ingredient in ingredients) {
    //...do something with the ingredient...
}
```

Either way, the point is that once you've fetched an object from your Core Data store, you don't need to do any more fetches to get related data. Core Data will do that for you behind the scenes. This is one of the things that makes Core Data compelling when compared to using a database directly.

Comment: Hey Caleb, thanks a lot for your answer, very detailed and exactly what I needed. I guess I'd go for your proposed model since that totally makes sense while my idea comes from the database-kind of thinking I guess. Thanks again! :)